# Background missing from compositor output

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

For some reason, the background I made in the compositing tab does not appear in renders, even though I got 'composite' checked in rendering window and post-processing is enabled as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to plug your Add node into the Composite node as well, not only into the Viewer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to plug your *Add* node into the *Composite* node as well, not only into the *Viewer*, otherwise what you see through the *Viewer* won't render:

[image]